# MS graph API adaptive card Action.Submit {type: "imBack"} not working on PC teams app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm using graph API to send an Adaptive card containing a number of options, listed as buttons.
and require the text value of the button to be sent back through the chat as if the user sent it.

(using python)

```
adaptive_card = {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.5",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit",
                "data": {
                    "msteams": {
                        "type": "imBack",
                        "value": "Get Order Status"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

card = {
        "subject": None,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<attachment id=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"></attachment>"
        },
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                "content": json.dumps(adaptive_card)
            }
        ]
   }
```

When pressing the button on the adaptive card on the mobile app it works as expected,
though when pressing the button on the PC MS-teams app it does nothing.

as requested, here is the log snippet of the desktop app:

```
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] useSlotConfigCallbacksAndCustomProperties: Entity options are (incorrectly) being asked for type and action that do not pertain to the entity. chats != chats or view != share, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462173852, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27307440, freeMemory: 4515139584, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] useSlotConfigCallbacksAndCustomProperties: Entity options are (incorrectly) being asked for type and action that do not pertain to the entity. chats != chats or view != share, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462173852, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27328756, freeMemory: 4515135488, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] useSlotConfigCallbacksAndCustomProperties: Entity options are (incorrectly) being asked for type and action that do not pertain to the entity. chats != chats or view != share, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462173870, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27367856, freeMemory: 4514861056, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] useSlotConfigCallbacksAndCustomProperties: Entity options are (incorrectly) being asked for type and action that do not pertain to the entity. chats != chats or view != share, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 462173871, stepDelta: 1, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27382976, freeMemory: 4514861056, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462173887, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27439248, freeMemory: 4514861056, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462173887, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27453968, freeMemory: 4514861056, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174072, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27507816, freeMemory: 4424298496, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174072, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27522680, freeMemory: 4424298496, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174155, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27567368, freeMemory: 4419440640, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174155, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27582344, freeMemory: 4419440640, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174185, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27603896, freeMemory: 4415299584, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174185, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27618616, freeMemory: 4415299584, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] chatServiceSubscriptionContainer: convId: 19:<Email>, replyChainId: -1:: cachedMessages is undefined!, status: success,  scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462174200, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27638720, freeMemory: 4415324160, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] chatServiceSubscriptionContainer: convId: 19:<Email>, replyChainId: -1:: cachedMessages is undefined!, status: success, , scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 462174201, stepDelta: 1, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27653440, freeMemory: 4415324160, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179444, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27732856, freeMemory: 4287361024, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179444, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27747992, freeMemory: 4287361024, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success,, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179591, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27823664, freeMemory: 4286967808, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success,  scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179591, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27838384, freeMemory: 4286963712, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179841, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27883952, freeMemory: 4284620800, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,  
<11088> -- event -- eventpdclevel: 1, errorMessage: https://: line 23: CID[main] ChatPane: consumption horizons mismatch with members - membersConsumptionHorizonLength:1 otherConsumptionHorizonsLength:0 membersLength:2, status: success, scenarioName: experience-renderer-console-error, name: experience-renderer-console-error, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 462179841, stepDelta: 0, Scenario.Mode: 1, AppInfo.Language: en-us, complianceEnvironmentType: 0, isDataCategorizationEnabled: true, userpdclevel: 0, processMemory: 27898816, freeMemory: 4284604416, clientType: desktop, AppInfo.ClientType: desktop, batterylevel: 1, pluggedin: true, Window.Focus: foreground, windowIsVisible: true, Window.Status: systray, UserInfo.TimeZone: +02:00, vdiMode: 0,
```

Comment: Could you please share the console log, so that we are investigate from our end?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - I've added the log snippet, couldnt really make anything out of it

Comment: We are not able to repro the scenario with python Sample. Could you please check it once?
Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.32970 (64-bit). 
Link- https://youtu.be/GcqDrexqd0Y
Reference sample-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/22fcff680a3e11006eb09b81ac5ed4de345933e2/archive/samples/python/15.handling-attachments/bots/attachments_bot.py#L135

Comment: I'm using Teams version - 1.5.00.31168 (64-bit), I'm not using the bot framework. a simple requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{0}/messages'....) call.
containing the mentioned card structure, and header containing bearer with token

Comment: We are able to repro that issue ,We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @Varun - Sorry for delay in response!!
We are actively checking the status of bug with engineering team and let you know the updates, if we have any.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - if you can please check on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76490719/ms-teams-graph-api-adaptive-card-to-send-response-on-button as well

Comment: @Varun - We got the reply through engineering team, For Graph API posted cards, we don't have JIT install design (because the app id is not there), so the bot won't be added to the context to allow such actions. This is expected behavior.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT - can something be done so that on click of button it replies to current message?

Comment: Are you trying something like below sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/csharp