# MS Teams + graph API adaptive card to send response on button

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am invoking MS teams graph API from nodeJS server

```
const response = await axios({
            url: `${GRAPH_ENDPOINT}/v1.0/chats/${chatId}/messages`,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data
        });
```

Where in `data` is as follows:

```
{
            "subject": null, //very important, it starts to send message from ms teams mobile app but not from windows app
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": "<attachment id=\"a1b2\"></attachment>"
            },
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "a1b2",
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    "contentUrl": null,
                    "content": JSON.stringify({
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                        "version": "1.2",
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "Submit",
                                "data": {
                                    "msteams": {
                                        "type": "imBack",
                                        "value": "Text to reply in chat"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }),
                    "name": null,
                    "thumbnailUrl": null
                }
            ]
        }
```

But clicking on the submit button doesn't send a reply back in the chat. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can the user send the bot a regular text message ok?

Comment: Yes user is able to send normal text messages.. My requirement is to get reply on the sent message based on the buttons

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow turns out ` "subject": "Missing Timesheet",` is the issue it has to be set to `null` but still on button click it doesnt revert it as reply

Comment: Is there any console error you are getting on clicking on submit button?

Comment: oh, good to know about the 'subject'. It makes me wonder if there's something else in the payload that's missing. It's worth considering if you should send the message using Bot Framework instead of Graph, using Proactive Messaging (see more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT No clue on how to check teams console error

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow - that will be once graph API proofs to be worthless for my scenarios... Update it works when responding from teams mobile app and not from windows app :( too many bugs with MS Teams it seems

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: I dont have admin center access @Prasad-MSFT

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT - can the same code be tried at your end? or are we expecting it to be some teams configuration issue

Comment: Is there a way I can get the response to card as reply to the same message

Comment: Did you try action type messageBack instead of imBack ? Could you please try that and check if it helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards

Comment: yes i did but same result

Comment: We tried as mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards) and it sent a card having `imBack` action button in the desired group chat. However on clicking on the button it doesn't respond anything. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK10f.png

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: @Varun -We got confirmation from engineering team that, this is by design. 'imBack' or 'messageBack' invoke won't work through Graph. Only 'openUrl' will.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.
'imBack' or 'messageBack' invoke won't work through Graph API.

Only 'openUrl' will work.